# Google Places API not working with getCurrentPosition Geolocation in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, geolocation, google-places-api

Trying to get Google Places API to notice my location and apply the functions below. Very new to this and not sure what I am doing wrong below as the API and all the functions works initially, but after I'm asked for my location, it shows where I am but nothing else works/aren't working together.

Cordova Geolocation plugin I added to my ionic app:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
```

**App.js**

```js
app.controller("MapController", function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

  var map;
  var infowindow;
  var request;
  var service;
  var markers = [];

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3625441, -71.0864435);
    var mapOptions = {
      center:center,
      zoom:16
    };

  map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
              map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
              var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                  map: map,
                  title: "My Location"
              });
          });

    $scope.map = map;

    request = {
        location: center,
        radius: 1650,
        types: ['bakery', 'bar']
    };

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

  function callback (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  function createMarker(place){
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map,this);
    });
  }

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the position, you update the map's location, but you don't run a new Nearby Search.

So I think you want to call `service.nearbySearch(...)` in the getCurrentPosition callback.

You may also want to have your nearbySearch callback keep an array of the markers created via `createMarker`, so you can remove them when you run a new search (e.g. by calling `marker.setMap(null)` on each old marker).